# Blazor WASM get current URL in program.cs

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Is there a way to get the URL from program.cs file?
I've seen an option with `@inject NavigationManager MyNavigationManager` but it is for components.

Comment: builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress

Comment: Are you trying to fix some other problem, hosting on a subdirectory perhaps? The (relative) root URL is set as the URL `base` in `index.html` so *all* relative requests use it as the base. You shouldn't need to check what the base URL is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So is this Blazor server-side or client-side? If it's client-side you can use the ***IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment*** to get the url. You can try this:

```
private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
{
    var baseAddress = hostEnvironment.BaseAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works and answers the question. Comments like "You shouldn't need to check what the base URL is" do not seem helpful to me.

In my case I am programmatically configuring an OIDC provider and need to formulate redirect URLs to receive the authorization response back at.  Seems like a perfectly legitimate use case and the answer here was very helpful.  I ended up with this code in my Program.cs:

```
string clientBaseUrl = builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress;
if(clientBaseUrl.EndsWith("/")) { clientBaseUrl = clientBaseUrl.TrimEnd('/'); }
Console.Out.WriteLine("clientBaseUrl: " + clientBaseUrl);
```